# Issue in adding Worklight 6.1 to watch OS 2.1 using xCode 7.3

Tags: xcode, swift, ibm-mobilefirst, watchos-2

We are working on a native iOS app which is using the Worklight 6.1 SDK, we need to implement a watch app which can use the SDK to get data from the server.

However, we couldn't add the Worklight SDK to the watch extension and here are details about the issue:

we followed the steps in this link: http://www.tricedesigns.com/2015/05/15/powering-apple-watch-with-ibm-mobilefirst-part-1/

When adding the "linked frameworks and libraries" we couldn't find "libstdc++.6.dylib" in xCode:

[image: libstdc++.6.dylib is missing]

and when we tried to continue and add the linker flag "-ObjC" there was a lot of errors in the project:

[image: Errors when adding -ObjC]

Please help to solve this issue if it's possible (if the Worklight SDK supports Watch OS 2.1), or provide me with steps for adding the Worklight SDK to the watch extension,

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worklight 6.1 does not support at all Watch OS 1 or 2.

Comment: Thank you, is it possible that I can integrate it if I'm developing a Worklight hybrid app?